# Балансировка маршрута

Tags: ping, маршрутизация, linux

Доброго времени суток!
К серверу (на убунте) подключено 3 сетевых интерфейса: eth0 (локалка), ppp0 (Интернет 1), ppp1 (Интернет 2), т.е. два интернет провайдера. Периодически с одним из этих двух провайдеров пропадает связь (или падает скорость). Как замутить автоматическую смену маршрута? 
Т.е. я могу пинговать каждый интерфейс, но как грамотнее прописать правила маршрутизации?

На вопрос "Зачем?" отвечаю: raspberryPI с двумя 3G модемами находится в автомобиле и раздаёт интернет.

*Обновление*

тут два момента:

1. связь может работать на обоих подключениях, но на одном хорошо, а на другом еле ползти, поэтому два пинга на каждый интерфейс и сравнение результатов.
2. я плохо разбираюсь в маршрутизации. меня хватило лишь на

   ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp0  scope link  metric 1000
   ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp1  scope link  metric 1000

а далее в зависимости от результатов пинга одна из строчек

```
ip route replace default via 192.168.1.2 dev ppp0  proto static
ip route replace default via 192.168.1.2 dev ppp1  proto static
```

но чую не в ту сторону копаю.

Comment: я бы дефолт вообще не трогал, помечал бы новые исходящие соединения, и вот для них бы менял роутинг.

    ip rule help 

вас интересует selector fwmark и action table,  (таблица создается с помошью 

    ip route add [правило] table name

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт, запускается раз в минуту, проверяет работосопособность сети, если сеть не работает проверяет какое используется подключение (например по состоянию таблицы маршрутизации) и переключается на другое.

Маршруты настраиваются утилитой `route`. Если что-то не понятно — спрашивай.

Comment: тут два момента:
1. связь может работать на обоих подключениях, но на одном хорошо, а на другом еле ползти, поэтому два пинга на каждый интерфейс и сравнение результатов.

2. я плохо разбираюсь в маршрутизации. меня хватило лишь на 

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp0  scope link  metric 1000
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp1  scope link  metric 1000

а далее в зависимости от результатов пинга одна из строчек

ip route replace default via 192.168.1.2 dev ppp0  proto static
ip route replace default via 192.168.1.2 dev ppp1  proto static

но чую не в ту сторону копаю.